# Running Bartender on a single machine over network

Tags: c#, remote-access, bartender

I am using Bartender Enterprise Automation edition for Label Printing. As of now, Bartender is installed on machines on which we intended to print the labels from.

Now, I have an windows forms C# application, which invokes Bartender Engine and prints the labels.

If a machine does not have Bartender Install on it, my app can not print the labels.

**So, is there a way to install Bartender on a single machine (let's say our production server which is up and running 24 X 7 and on local network connected to each and every machine ) and whenever "Print Label" button is pressed from my Windows Forms application, necessary data and Label Template file (.btw) will be sent to that machine and that remote machine will print the labels for me.**

this way I won't require to install bartender each and every machine in my company. I did try looking for the solution online but there isn't much documentation for this online.

Please share some knowledge if someone have explored in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Bartender do have support for Web Print Server , I am not sure if it is available for the version you mentioned.
It works like this : https://www.barcodesinc.com/news/?p=3203
http://www.seagullscientific.com/media/101387/web-based-barcode-and-label-printing.pdf

[image]

These are some helpful links related to this topic :

Comment: I forgot to mention that at times we won't be connected to internet and still this app needs to work over local network. So, I really need something which can work on LAN.

Comment: Not sure about that, you might find what you are looking for in those articles though

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this and seeking solution as you have asked but no luck. Unfortunately you have to install BarTender suite on each client. My organization has purchased enterprise license **2016** and I thought that [Print Portal](https://www.seagullscientific.com/media/101731/bartender-print-portal-201511.pdf) and [Print Maestro](https://www.seagullscientific.com/media/101377/bartender-printer-maestro-201511.pdf) might solve this problem but they both are developed for different purpose.

I haven't tried both of them yet. If you find anything, let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this with using BarTender Integration. Integration is used to automatically print labels without having a user see BarTender. If you can export your data to a csv file and drop it in a folder BarTender Integration will be able to pick it up and print it to the correct template. The integration will run from a server so you don't need to install it on every computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, since you do not like to install Bartender all over the machines in your company. Then i suggest you to create another windows form c# application to communicate with the one you have originally to print labels.

You should be able to print labels to **different printers through local network**.

**PC A**

> Installed Bartender and Have the windows form c# application to print labels

**PC B**

> Do not have Bartender installed
>
> Have another windows form c# application to send information to PC A

[image]